# Avoid extra dimension added by numpy.vsplit

Tags: python, numpy

We can join several 1d arrays with `vstack` (or `hstack`), e.g. `D = np.vstack([a,b,c])`.
The reverse operation is `[a2,b2,c2] = np.vsplit(D, 3)`. 
But the dimensionality changes in the round-trip:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,)
b = np.random.rand(10,)
c = np.random.rand(10,)
D = np.vstack([a,b,c])
[a2,b2,c2] = np.vsplit(D, 3)

>>> a.shape
(10,)

>>> a2.shape
(1, 10)
```

I know about squeeze to remove a dimension:

```
>>> a2.squeeze().shape
(10,)
```

But this is cumbersome, especially when splitting more than a couple of arrays.

Is there any way to 'automatically' perform a squeeze, or otherwise control the output of vsplit to avoid the mismatch in dimensions?

(the [split docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) do not mention any way to control the output dimensions as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [98]: D = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [99]: np.vsplit(D, 4)
Out[99]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2]]),
 array([[3, 4, 5]]),
 array([[6, 7, 8]]),
 array([[ 9, 10, 11]])]
```

`split` is using a slice to select rows, thus preserving that dimension

```
[D[i:i+1,:] for i in range(4)]
```

That's a general behavior that lets it return other size splits.

But it appears you want to return one row at a time.  There are many ways of doing this:

It's easy to apply `squeeze` iteratively (and not much more expensive, since `split` is already iterating):

```
In [100]: [np.squeeze(x) for x in np.vsplit(D, 4)]
Out[100]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

Or you can use a plain list comprehension:

```
In [101]: [x for x in D]
Out[101]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

Or convert the array to a list (this is different from `D.tolist()`:

```
In [102]: list(D)
Out[102]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

Or iteration by index.  This is like `split`, but uses a scalar index rather than the slice.  It's good to understand the difference between `D[i,:]` and `D[i:i+1, :]`.

```
In [103]: [D[i] for i in range(4)]
Out[103]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

Since you are using unpacking, you don't need any of this.  The unpacking will do the row 'iteration' for you:

```
In [106]: a,b,c,d = D
In [107]: a,b,c,d
Out[107]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11]))
```

Comment: This is a very informative answer, thank you! The best I had come up with was the squeezing list comprehension, but it seems still to be less clean than a built-in approach.

Comment: To have a MVCE I showed creation and attempted splitting, and picked the "v" versions (vstack and vsplit). But naturally I don't always have control over the input data organisation (e.g. if from an online database).  So the row iteration is a special case -- and very clean when it does work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,)
b = np.random.rand(10,)
c = np.random.rand(10,)
D = np.vstack([a,b,c])
[a2,b2,c2]=[D[x,:] for x in range(3)]

print(a2.shape)
```

output:

```
(10,)
```