# Split n-dimension Numpy array into list of n * (n-1)-dimension arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a Numpy array of shape (x, y, z...)

I want to turn this into a list of x arrays of shape (y, z...)

What is the easiest or most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: did you try `list(<your_array>)`?

Comment: `list(array)` works.  But usually if you feel the need to do this you have an XY problem with broadcasting.  Perhaps try asking the question you think creating this list solves.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks! Solved. I was trying to save a list of arrays as a .npy file and needed to retrieve this in its original format. Not sure if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: you can `np.save` an `array` of any dimension, no nead to break it up into a list unless you only want to save and load it back one part at a time.  Even then, using `np.memmap` or `dask` is probably better.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703171/avoid-extra-dimension-added-by-numpy-vsplit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873896/numpy-to-list-over-2nd-axis